# Retrieving POST data from jQuery in Django without a form

Tags: django, post, jquery

I am currently able to use the `post` method of jQuery to a view pointed by *myurl*

```
 jQuery.post("/myurl", {'value1':value1, 'value2':value2,
                        'csrftoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'}, 
             function(data) {
                        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
                            });
```

However, I don't know how to retrieve the posted data inside the view without using a form:

```
 def save_user_graph(request):
      if request.method == 'POST': 
            return HttpResponse(request.POST.get('value1'),status=201)
```

returns `None`.

Comment: This should work as you have described. What returns None? Your HTTP response, or `request.POST.get('value1')`? What values are you passing? Try using pdb to find out which values you are receiving.

Comment: That's pretty unreadable code, but the idea is right. Have you tried splitting it up and putting in some logging so you can see what the value of `value1` is?

Comment: I have put an `alert(value1);` before the jquery post and it has the right value. It is the not the http response that returns the None because i've tryed other variables which are passed correctly.

Comment: Sigh. If you're having problems with some code, *break it up*, then *log the individual bits*. So, log `request.method`. Then log the value of `request.POST.get('value1')`. Then, log the HttpResponse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `save_user_graph` is returning None, then request.method is not POST. If `save_user_graph` is returning an HttpResponse with the word 'None' in it, then `value1` isn't being sent correctly. Can you clarify which is the case?

If you have chrome, try navigating to the page with the developer toolbar open. You can go to the 'console' tab and view the AJAX request and see what data was sent with it, to make sure that the data was sent correctly.

Similarly, if you have firefox and firebug, you can go to the page and watch the ajax request and check the post parameters.

Assuming that the javascript works, you'll want to log request.POST in `save_user_graph`. In a pinch, you can just `print request.POST` and, assuming you're using the django dev server, the output will be printed in the dev server output.

We'll need a bit more debugging info before we can give a better answer. :)